# Ошибка Unexpected identifier при использовании setInterval. Повторный запуск функции в сервисе (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, rxjs

Есть функция:

```
public runGetAccessjwtTokenSheduler() {
    this.getAccessTokenIntervalId =
    setInterval(() => {this.updateAccessjwtToken().subscribe()}, 
    AccessTokenLifeTime - 5000);
}
```

Первый раз setInterval срабатывает нормально. Все остальные итерации выдают ошибку:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Есть мнение, что ошибка возникает из-за отсутствия объекта сервиса this в контекста вызова функции, но я же не могу создавать объект при каждой итерации или делать его статическим. (Со статическим сервисом все работает)

Текущее решение:

```
const AccessTokenLifeTime = 15000;

@Injectable()
export class SchedulerService {

  private static _authService: AuthorizationService = null;

  private static AccessTokenTimer: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService) {
    SchedulerService._authService = authService;
  }

  public static stopUpdateAccessJwtTokenLoop() {
    clearInterval(SchedulerService.AccessTokenTimer);
  }

 public static runUpdateAccessJwtTokenLoop() {
    SchedulerService.AccessTokenTimer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Update access Jwt token loop is working.");
     if (AuthorizationService.isAuthorized && SchedulerService._authService != null) {
        SchedulerService._authService.updateAccessjwtToken().subscribe();
     }
   }, AccessTokenLifeTime - 5000);
  }
}
```

Как правильно повторять функцию в сервисе?

**Update: решил проблему использовав сервис в корневом компоненте**

Comment: отсутствие (?) `this`  не является *синтаксической* ошибкой. Где находится показанный код?

Comment: @Igor код находится внутри сервиса AuthorizationService. Если сделать его статических, то все работает, но я так делать не хочу

Answer (score 1):

В RxJS есть встроенный механизм для решения этой задачи. И не надо ставить проверку платформы на SSR(Server Side Rendering).

```
var source = Rx.Observable
    .interval(500 /* ms */)
    .timeInterval();

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

// => Next: {value: 0, interval: 500}
// => Next: {value: 1, interval: 500}
// => Next: {value: 2, interval: 500}
// => Completed
```